# NL-SAS disk in desktop PCIe SAS controller. Does it work?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, desktop-computer, pci-express, sas

I have recently got the idea of deploying a home NAS, since I got a used SAS disk online.

But now I realised it's a nearline SAS disk, and I preemptively bought a SAS controller for my desktop motherboard not knowing if the connection would work.

The disk is a [16TB Western Digital DC HC550](https://serverpartdeals.com/products/western-digital-ultrastar-dc-hc550-wuh721816al5204-0f38357-16tb-7-2k-rpm-sas-12gb-s-512e-3-5-hard-drive) and the controller is a [LSI Broadcom 9300-8i](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00DSURZYS)

I haven't got any cable for the disk, since I don´t know what connector the disk uses and the specs aren't very clear, but it seems to have around 26 pins. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Back when I used similar LSI card in my desktop PC I used  cable like this one:   (link to a mni SAS SFF-8643 to (4x) 29pin SFF-8482 connectors with IDE power     https://www.amazon.com/CableCreation-Internal-SFF-8643-SFF-8482-connectors/dp/B01F378UF6/ref=sr_1_13?crid=6Y7YCSZ9NLEI&keywords=SFF-8643+to+SAS&qid=1696372587&sprefix=sff-8643+to+sas%2Caps%2C148&sr=8-13     I guess these days you probably could use SATA power instead.  That was in the old SAS 3.0 times, so caveat emptor.